# Pandas,(Python) -> Export to xlsx with multiple sheets

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

i`m traind to read some .xlsx files from a directory that is create earlier using curent timestamp and the files are store there, now i want to read those .xlsx files and put them in only one .xlsx files with multiple sheets, but i tried multiple ways and didnt work, i tried:

final file Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx

the script i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timestampdirectory import  createdir
import os
dest = createdir()
dfSvnUsers = pd.read_csv(dest, "SvnUsers.xlsx")
dfSvnGroupMembership = pd.read_csv(dest, "SvnGroupMembership.xlsx")

xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter("Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx")
dfSvnUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnUsers', index = False )
dfSvnGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnGroupMembership', index = False )
xlwriter.close()
```

[the folder that is created automaticaly with curent timestamp that contains files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfMdI.png)

[this is one of file that file that i want to add as sheet in that final xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV2Fh.png)

[this is how i create the director with curent time and return dest to export the files in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWVXt.png)

I change a bit the script, now its how it looks like, still getting error :

> File "D:\Py_location_projects\testfi\Usage-SvnAnalysis.py", line 8, in
>
> with open(file, 'r') as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SvnGroupMembership.xlsx'

the files exist, but the script cant take the root path to that directory because i create that directory on other script using timestamp and i returned the path using dest

`dest=createdir()` represent the path where the files is, what i need to do its just acces this dest an read the files from there and export them in only 1 xlsx as sheets of him , in this cas sheet1 and sheet2, because i tried to reat only 2 files from that dir

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timestampdirectory import  createdir
import os
dest = createdir()
files = os.listdir(dest)
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        dfSvnUsers = open(os.path.join(dest, 'SvnUsers.xlsx'))
        dfSvnGroupMembership = open(os.path.join(dest, 'SvnGroupMembership.xlsx'))

xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter("Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx")
dfSvnUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnUsers', index = False )
dfSvnGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnGroupMembership', index = False )
xlwriter.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try read Excel files use `pd.read_excel` instead of `pd.read_csv`.

```
import os
dfSvnUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnUsers.xlsx"))
dfSvnGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnGroupMembership.xlsx"))
```

Comment: [Photo with script](https://imgur.com/a/UHm7Bdd)  i tried but i have the same error @brendon idk how to fix it

Comment: `read_excel` should read a file not a folder. I have edited the answer.You can try this again.@Champs

Comment: [UPDATED SCRIPT](https://imgur.com/a/wBA4tj8) i updated and trying something else but still not working

Comment: I don't think you need to use `open`  and loop to read the file, just use `pd.read_excel`, and make sure the first parameter is the relative path or absolute path of the Excel file.The key to the last few errors is that the file path is incorrect.